# How to clear the cookies and set smsession as loggedoff once logout button click

Tags: cookies

I used sencha tool for mobile app and in login  tried to open a dynamic restfulweb service page which has created in tomcat 6 server. And when click on logout it will take to main page.

So if again click on login which app was opened in chrome explorer, which again taken to inside app where the previous session is still alive and without giving user name and password is entered the app.

My requirement was once logoff button click active cookies SMSESSION or all active cookie should be expired by adding the code in logoff button key press function in Sencha Tool.

When I logout from app created in Sencha tool, it's logging out but again when click on login it's taking into the application without giving the username, password.

How could I clear the cookies active or set SMSESSION as LOGGEDOFF in EXTJS tool?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for the caching issue is settingdocument.cookie=”SMSESSION=loggedoff”in Javascript but this is working only when we open chrome without disabling web security. This is not working in both Chrome web security enabled as well as in mobile device.

To fix this issue, I have handled setting cookie at server end code(through web service) in response object. Whenever user clicks on log off in mobile device a new web service called logoff will be invoked which will set the cookie value of SMSESSION to loggedoff, code as below.

response.addCookie(new Cookie("SMSESSION", "loggedoff"));

To revoke this cookie or make it expire, whenever user try to login, in getUser web service have included 3 more line to set the age of the cookie to 0(means expire), code as below

Cookie cook = new Cookie("SMSESSION", "loggedoff");

cook.setMaxAge(0);

response.addCookie(cook);

Comment: You should also set the http only flag to prevent XSS attacks stealing users cookies. [1]: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly

Comment: You should also invalidate the old value of SMSESSION in case the user does not click log off.